# Why cannot add row to jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I need some help with addrow to jTable.

I have 2 jFrames, first one has jTable1 and second one has jTextfields. I would like to add data (string) from second frame to jTable1 in first frame. I tried many versions and watch many tutorials..but no success.

in first frame where i have jTable1 i have SwingWorker and i wrote:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         jButton1.setEnabled(false);
         jButton2.setEnabled(true);
         Boolean praznaMapa = false;         
         worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
 
                if(isCancelled())
                {
                    return null;
                }
                AddRowToTable(new Object[]
                {
                    PrviStolpec,DrugiStolpec,TretjiStolpec,timeStamp,
                });
}}
worker.execute();}

     public static void AddRowToTable (Object [] data)
    {
       
        DefaultTableModel tblmodel = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        tblmodel.insertRow(0, data);
    }
```

and in the second frame where i have textfields i wrote:

```
String PrviStolpec = FIRSTFRAME_Okno.withoutExtension;
String DrugiStolpec = "OK";
String TretjiStolpec = FIRSTFRAME_Okno.stSledenja;
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                FIRSTFRAME_Okno.AddRowToTable(new Object[]
                {
                    PrviStolpec,DrugiStolpec,TretjiStolpec,timeStamp,
                });     
                FIRSTFRAME_Okno.jTable1.setSelectionBackground(Color.green);
```

but when i run program, nothing happen. No error and no data in jTable1 :(

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: Not answering your question, I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead for getting the current time as a string use `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))` using classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V. tnx for the note!

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]?

Comment: 1) Method names should NOT start with an upper case character. 2) Variable names should not start with an upper case character. Learn and follow Java conventions. 3) An application should only have a single JFrame. If you need child windows then you can use a `JDialog`. 4) You should NOT be using code like: `FIRSTFRAME_Okno.jTable1` to access variables of another class. If you want to update the table then you pass the "table" as a parameter to your child dialog. If the child dialog has a reference to the visible table, then the above code should work.

Comment: @camickr thank you for answer! I updated my question. I think i have problem with SwingWorker which i have in first jframe.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution!

It is really stupid one, but anyway...

I have in second class:

```
FIRSTFRAME_Okno = new FIRSTFRAME_Okno();
```

Because of that jTable1 was not updated.

Every function which i call from second class i use:

```
FIRSTFRAME_Okno.functionName();
```

Tnx!